# How can i get the RawUrl in asp.net code?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I would like to get the RAW url dynamically in my ASP.NET webpage but i cannot figure out how to do it. Something like the dummy code below...

```
<div id="fb-root">
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
 <fb:comments href= '<% REQUEST_RAW_URL %>' num_posts="2" width="592"></fb:comments>
</div>
```

You see i would like to use it in the facebook comments box.

**UPDATE**: And here is the Url rewrite rule that i use

```
<add name="Rule1" virtualUrl="^~/temp/(.*)/(.*).aspx" 
rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString" 
destinationUrl="~/Directory/page.aspx?ItemID=$1&amp;id=$2&amp;lng=gr"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the `<fb:comments>...</fb:comments>` tag? Is this a server side tag? If so, you need to add `runat="server"` to the properties to make it interpreted server-side.

Try this:

```
<fb:comments href='<%=HttpContext.Request.RawUrl %>' num_posts="2" width="592" 
    runat="server"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<%= Request.Url.AbsoluteUri %>
```

Comment: @Chocol8, what does, 'It does not work' mean? If you want help provide more information on what's happening and what you're expecting.

Comment: I think it has to do with Url rewriting. I use Url Rewrite. Please take a look at the update. Thank tou